# SSH Tunneling to box behind firewall

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall

I've got a computer behind a firewall, a home desktop, and a server.  I can reverse ssh tunnel to the server from computer_behind_firewall, and then

```
ssh  localhost -p some_port
```

while on the server, but it doesn't work if I try to

```
ssh my_server -p some_port
```

from home.  I've disabled iptables to make sure it's not a firewall issue, and that hasn't helped.

What do I need to make my Ménage à trois of servers work out?

Ideally I'd like to port forward http on certain requests to the machine behind the firewall.

Comment: Sounds like a SuperUser question

Comment: A picture of the network scenario would be worth 1k words.

Answer (score 2):

From the SSH documentation on [Port Forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/#FIG-SSH2-TUNNEL-2):

> It is important to realize that if you have three hosts, client, sshdserver, and appserver, and you forward the traffic coming to the client's port x to the appserver's port y, only the connection between the client and sshdserver will be secured. See Figure Forwarding to a third host. The command you use would be something like the following:
>
> ```
> ssh2 -L x:appserver:y username@sshdserver
> ```
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [ssh.com](http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/tunnel2-2.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a reverse ssh tunnel with the server, you're probably looking for "-g" option.

```
-g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
```

Otherwise only localhost will be allowed to use your tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question or rather, what the problem is and what you want to achieve. Also, this is not a coding question, but I'll try to dig into it.

Do you want to tunnel TCP connections through SSH to computer_behind_firewall through the server from outside the firewall? And this SSH connection to server fails? If so, you should run `tcpdump tcp PORT` on the server to see if really no packets arrive. If they arrive, your sshd or TCP wrapper are configured to not accept connections from outside (check /etc/ssh/sshd_config, /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow). Also look into the logfiles in /var/log. If no packets arrive, there is a firewall either at the sending end or on the gateway to the LAN of the server that is blocking or not forwarding into the private network.